# MVVM RelayCommand parameter null

Tags: c#, wpf, relaycommand

I'm struggling with a problem related to the RelayCommand class. I'm trying to pass a parameter to a method to execute through the RelayCommand but I cannot make it work. The method is correctly called but the param passed is always null.

My RelayCommand class:

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
        //
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

I'm trying to pass a simple text value

```
<Button
   Margin="0,8,8,0"
   Content="Ok"
   IsDefault="True"
   CommandParameter="Sample"
   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <i:EventTrigger
                 EventName="Click">                                        
                 <i:InvokeCommandAction
                     Command="{Binding CreateNewCommand}" />
             </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Button>
```

My Command:

```
public ICommand CreateNewCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return  new RelayCommand(param => CreateNew(param)); 
        }
    }
```

No matter what the obj is always null.

```
private void CreateNew(object obj)
    {
        // obj is null
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't use the Interaction.Trigger. It's absolutely redundant and only clutters your source code. Simply assign/bind the command instance to the Button.Command property (you are already using the Button.CommandParameter property).

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the mvvm community toolkit nuget.

Comment: Additionally it is absolutely valid to handle events in the code-behind. Interaction triggers are usually not helpful and tend to introduce code smells as UI events are not meant to be handled in any model (that's why they are usually routed events). For "events" that are meant to be handled by models WPF introduced the ICommandSource interface to enable the commanding infrastructure. This is a design decision that WPF controls don't implement ICommandSource. Frameworks usually enforce a clean coding style.

Comment: Only those that trigger business operations implement that interface (only a handful controls implement this interface like Button and MenuItem). And you don't need any 3rd party library like xzy toolkit and their likes to solve your problem. Ignore such recommendations. Simply set the Button.Command property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CommandParamter` has to be passed on the `InvokeCommandAction`, not the `Button`:

```
<Button
   Margin="0,8,8,0"
   Content="Ok"
   IsDefault="True"   
   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <i:EventTrigger
                 EventName="Click">                                        
                 <i:InvokeCommandAction
                     Command="{Binding CreateNewCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="Sample" />
             </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simply bind the Button's `Command` property:

```
<Button ...
    Command="{Binding CreateNewCommand}"
    CommandParameter="Sample" />
```